# Synchronizing input, desktop video capture, and sound capture on Linux

Tags: linux, input, capture, wayland, screen-recording

How can I programmatically record desktop video on Linux with sound and input gestures, and have it synchronized?

Simple for the input - the events have timestamp field.

P.S. Ability to encode video in hardware  is a requirement, as this will run continuously.